# MVC default document under folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

So in IIS you can set the default document for all site folders to be say "index.aspx".

In MVC how do I do this across a) all directories or failing that b) one directory at a time.

I have a page in [Views]/[Search]/[index.aspx]

This url works - www.[mysite]/search/index
but I can't get it to work under - www.[mysite]/search

I have tried adding this into global.asax > RegisterRoutes

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                "Search",
                "{action}",
                new { controller = "Search", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Comment: Can you show us your entire RegisterRoutes method?

Comment: In the Model-View-Controller world, the only thing a user interacts with is an Action on a Controller. If you're talking about a default Action among your routes, this is very different from a "default document".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC doesn't use a default document, but a default route.

Your route above shows us that the default page when someone visits your website (http://example.com) will be the `Index` view contained within the `search` directory.

---

The default route that gets generated with a new MVC project looks like this

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

What this means is that your routing structure would look like

- http://example.com/ (showing the "index" view within the "home" folder)
- http://example.com/about/ (showing the "index" view within the "about" folder)
- http://example.com/about/contact (showing the "contact" view within the "about" folder)

Comment: My mistake. I had another routing script causing a conflict. The other script was pushing all documents in the home directory to be recognised from the root dir.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need this route. The default route should work fine as it specifies a default controller and action which you could modify to match your requirements. Thus if the user requests `/` this default controller and action should be executed. This would work out of the box on IIS7 but on II6 it won't work because you cannot have extensionless urls by default. You might take a look at the following [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) if you are running on IIS6.